# Documentation of data with R package

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2, tidyverse

Using `roxygen2` and `devtools` to author my own package.

I have some data I would like to include with my package (stored at `data/mydata.rda`).

I have documented this data in roxygen format at `R/mydata.R`:

```
#'This is my data
#'
#'This is my description
#'
#'@name mydata
#'@docType data
##### omitting @format for brevity
"mydata"
```

In `DESCRIPTION`, I have `LazyData: true`

Yet when I run `document()`, I get an error message that "`mydata` is not an exported object from `'namespace: mypackage'`"

What gives? [Hadley's guide](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) says never to `export` data, and you are not supposed to directly edit `NAMESPACE` when using roxygen2, so I am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Please try to make a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can see exactly what you've attempted and can re-create the error ourselves so we can test and offer a specific solution.

Comment: @J_F I was not, but adding `@name mydata` did not resolve the problem

Comment: This fixed it - if you write it as a comment, I will accept it as the answer. Mind explaining why this works so it is not pure magic?

Comment: I retract the previous comment - still is not working.

Comment: Did you have mydata.R exported in the DESCRIPTION? If you have the "Collate" filed, you also have to write `mydata.R' here.

Comment: You don't export things in DESCRIPTION. And the documentation explicitly says to not @export data in the .R file.

Comment: I don't mean export in that way using @export. See for example here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/data.R and then they also mention data.R in Collate in their DESCRIPTION file.